# Is it possible to customize Ubuntu's boot screen?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, live-cd

When we boot up a Ubuntu CD, it will first pop-up a language selection screen and let us choose a language.

Then, it will show us a list of options that we can do using this CD:-

1. Try Ubuntu without any change to your computer
2. Install Ubuntu
3. ...
4. Boot from first hard disk

I plan to modify the Ubuntu CD's iso image and create a customized installation CD. For example, i want the CD to automatically choose English as the default language without showing the selection screen.

I also plan to modify the text in the list of options to:-

1. Boot Ubuntu Live CD
2. Install Ubuntu into this PC
3. Exit

Is it possible to customize these boot screens in the Ubuntu iso image and create a new installation CD?

Can anyone give me some advices how can I do this?

Comment: This may have been better on http://ubuntu.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu you see is actually just `grub`.  You'll probably want to look at the Ubuntu documentation for [creating your own LiveCD](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization); you'll probably want to edit the grub configuration files, which *should* be located in `/boot/grub` or something similar (the configuration is called either `menu.lst` or `grub.conf`).

Configuration help for grub can be found via the Google. :)

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

This is actually going to be a lot trickier then you expect, as you will have to modify the boot CD, which I believe uses CramFS, and you will have to rebuild said CD each time a new version of ubuntu comes out.

This link is a guide on how to automate the install program

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html

You may also find this tool handy

http://maketecheasier.com/reconstructor-creating-your-own-ubuntu-distribution/2008/07/05